# Ignore keypress when alert shown on Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, alert, keypress

I have a function X doing something when the cursor is focused in a textbox and I press an enter, however there is a possibility (with other JS function) that, if I focus on this textbox, I got an alert.

The problem happens here, sometimes I "ignore" the error by pressing the <kbd>enter</kbd>, how not to call this function X when the alert's there, but I want it to work again when the alert is closed again.

On HTML page:

```
<input type='text' name='col0' id='col0' onkeyup='arrowHandler(0);'
onblur='count(0)' />
<input type='text' name='col1' id='col1' onkeyup='arrowHandler(1);' 
onblur='count(1)' />
<input type='text' name='col2' id='col2' onkeyup='arrowHandler(2);' 
onblur='count(2)' />
<input type='text' name='col3' id='col3' onkeyup='arrowHandler(3);' 
onblur='count(3)' />
```

On JS page:

```
function arrowHandler(i){
  var key = window.event.keyCode;
  if(key == 13){
    // moving to the next (or first, if last) text field
    var newcol = parseInt(i) + 1;
    if(newcol == col) newcol = 0;
    elmt = document.getElementById("col" + newcol);
    elmt.focus();
  }
}

function count(i){
  if(parseInt(document.getElementById("col" + i).value) > 20){
    alert("error!");
  }
}
```

Here, when the focus is in `col0`, I write 25, then the focus moves to `col1`, I got an alert, then I press enter, and as the result, the focus moves to `col2` (I don't want the last movement because of pressing enter when alert shown).

Comment: could you be more clear? or better can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Jivings: done, sorry I was too lazy before :)

Comment: please anyone downvoted, remove the downvote (I don't mind not getting upvoted)

Comment: It was me, since you edited, I can remove it :)

Comment: Please paste code that actually works; both functions have errors in them, so I'm surprised it can work at all. Plus it only works in IE, but I assume that's intended?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
var block = false;

function arrowHandler(evt, i){
  var key = window.event.keyCode;
  if(!block && key == 13){
    // moving to the next (or first, if last) text field
    var newcol = parseInt(i) + 1;
    if(newcol == col) newcol = 0;
    elmt = document.getElementById("col" + newcol);
    elmt.focus();
  }
}

function count(i){
  if(parseInt(document.getElementById("col" + i)).value > 20){
    block = true;
    alert("error!");
    setTimeout(function(){block=false;},100);
  }
}
```

Which, as `alert` stops JS execution, ignore any key presses immediately after the alert.

Although, you probably should reconsider using the `alert`, there are much better ways to do validation.

Comment: the best answer so far... And the second advice not to use alert, I'm starting thinking about that...

Comment: hey, you may like to make that window.event.keyCode - 4th line

Comment: @ParthThakkar: yes, I was mistaken, but that's not the point anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I guess it should work:

You could use a global temp variable say t & set it to 1 when you alert "error!". Then in your arrowHandler function change the if condition to if(key==13 && t==0) followed by your code & add an else part to it where you change t=0.

Also, I guess your `parseInt(document.getElementById("col" + i))>20` statement should be replaced by `parseInt(document.getElementById("col" + i).value)>20`.

Comment: regarding the .value, yes, I had that actually, sorry, it's because I only took some of the code, and might be forgetting something (the real one was too long to copy)... And yes, the code works! thx

Comment: I hate to say this, but this isn't working all the time... So, now I add the t=0 after alert, and having t=1 after pressing enter when t=0. This works if I "click" ok by pressing enter (when alert comes), but this doesn't work if I actually click the ok button (the t value is still 0 after)

Comment: additional, I worked the way around, t==1 works, t==0 doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd not use `alert()` but rather pop up a `<div>` styled nicely that would gain focus, or show a `<span>` that indicates the failure message without forcing the user to acknowledge it.

If you choose to stick with the `alert()` solution, @gopi1410 is correct: set a var before and clear it after that means "don't filter keystrokes".

Comment: Since I choose to stick the `alert()`, I don't find that solution works. The problem is, when I'm clicking the `OK` on alert, the variable's value doesn't change. Hence, the `enter` doesn't work as I want after that

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler version. Handling focus is done in a separate function. No need for timers and all. Hope this helps.

And as others have said, please avoid using alert, please - it's really irritating if you find such a thing, isn't it? Think over it.

```
var handleFocus = function (i, error) {
    var id = "col" + (error ? i : ++i);
    if (id === 'col' + col) id = 'col0';
    alert(id + "  " + i + "  " + error)
    document.getElementById(id).focus();
};

var arrowHandler = function (evt, i) {
    var key = window.event.keyCode;
    if (key == 13) {
        handleFocus(i, false);
    }
};

var count = function (i) {
    if (parseInt(document.getElementById("col" + i).value) > 20) {
        alert("error!");
        handleFocus(i, true);
    }
};
```

Comment: still don't get it... when there's an alert and I press Enter, will the arrowHandler be executed? If so, what's the difference?

Comment: No. It won't. But we don't need it to be called, do we? Since we are delegating the work of handling focus to a separate function - handleFocus(). The reason for this separation is that otherwise the code will be repeated, a bad thing.

Comment: so how would the code be on the html-page? which called which?

Comment: All right. arrowHandler() is bound to keyup/down whatever you wish. count() is bound to change(). Whereas handleFocus is not bound to anything, it's just used by the former two.

Comment: then, since "enter" is on keyup/down, it will also be executed when it is on alert, right?

Comment: you mean "enter" on the alert box? if so, then it (probably) WILL emit a keyup/down event, but not on your input element.

Answer (score 0):

u can use **count** function inside **arrowHandler** inside if(key == 13) condition and adding **return false** in count function

(i will ameliorate my answer when i had time)